# Best way to detect if a column value is included in another table's column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the best (more efficient) way to detect if, for instance, TableX->Field1 value is included in TableY->Field2. With TableY->Field2 being a concatenation of several TableX->Field1 values

Sample Data:

```
Table X   |   Table Y
          |
Field1    |   Field2             FieldStatus
          |
orange    |   orange, mango       Active
pear      |   pear, orange        Active
mango     |   orange, pear        Active
banana    |   pear, mango         Active
```

The expected result would be:

```
orange
pear
mango
```

As those are the values in TableX->Field1 included in at least one entry of TableY->Field2.

I am trying with this code:

```
SELECT  *
FROM TableX
WHERE ( SELECT TOP 1 FieldStatus
        FROM TableY
        WHERE CONTAINS (TableY.Field2, TableX.Field1) --Won't work
        ORDER BY TableY.Date DESC) = 'Active'
```

But it seems the T-SQL function "CONTAINS" doesn't work in this scenario, and I think "LIKE" would be quite expensive (inefficient?)

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do YOU mean by "contains"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: "Contains" as the T-SQL "CONTAINS" function: WHERE CONTAINS (TableY.Field2, TableX.Field1)

Comment: A "better way" to do it is to not have a column that contains a concatenation of several values. This kind of  column is almost always an indication of a poor database design decision. Normalizing such a table to first normal form is almost always the way to go.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson I agree and appreciate your advice, but that's not in my power. I need to deal with what I have

Comment: If proper database normalize is not an option, *split the columns first into derived tables* and join on that. There are both UDF and CLR-UDF options available to do this is SQL Server (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=split+comma+separated+value+sql+server). The problem itself will only scale with a pre-reduced (or pre-materialized) set due to lack of fundamental normalization and indices.

Answer (score 0):

There is no efficient way of doing this.  You have to do painful row-by-row comparisons of the strings, and that would be:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM TableX x
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TableY
              WHERE ', ' + y.field2 + ', ' LIKE '%, ' + x.Field1) + ', %'
                    y.FieldStatus = 'Active'
             )
```